# software architecture ajax and restfull web services

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, rest

I am working on a web project. I want to create the client side of a web application using  bootstrap , jquery-ui and ajax, and the server side with restfull webservice made with c# and hosted by an iis server. i don't know if its a good architecture. what to do you thing about?!

Comment: If you asking which one is better: Soap or rest. I would say I prefer rest

Comment: Yes. but is it a good idea to make the entire presentation layer of my web application with boostrap, ajax and jquery-ui,

Answer (score 1):

RESTful server and JS client leads to Single Page Applications. Whether it is a good architecture is upon everyone's opinion but it is used a lot these days. For Single Page Application consider using some JS framework like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).